# Multi-instance learning for time-spatio-dependent data

Tags: deep-learning, attention, multiclass-classification

I am trying to use MIL approach from the paper [Attention-based Deep Multiple Instance Learning](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1802.04712.pdf) on the data that is a frames of human pose images acquired on different angle on each timepoint (temporal dependency). Bag (sample) is a tensor with size `[batch, frames, channel, height, weight]`, each instance (frame) of the bag could contain one type of image error (pose error) (11 classes of errors). I want to classify type of the error that bag have and then evaluate which of the frames was assigned as one containing errors.
From the original paper in chapter 2.1, they stated that "In the MIL setting the bag probability theta(x) must be permutation-invariant since we assume neither ordering nor dependency of instances within a bag."

I am wondering, if I assume that instances of a bag could be dependent, and bag is not permutation-invariant. Could I still use MIL approach in this case?